# Cross-Sections of Solids

Tags: conic-sections, solid-geometry, cross-sections

I know already that conic sections (or conics) have been widely explored and many things about them are already known. I was wondering if this sort of exploration has taken place for any other sorts of solids. Spheres, of course, are easy, since each cross section is a circle. I was wondering about things like cylinders, paraboloids, or tori. I am most intrigued by the torus, especially after noticing that, when cut the right way, the cross section forms the shape of a lemniscate.

Does anyone know if the cross sections of any other solids have been investigated already?

Comment: I would be astounded if the cross-sectional properties of every class of three-dimensional solid haven't been fully studied, enumerated and classified.  These are used in computer graphics and CAD software too, of course.

Comment: So would I, but when I google "Toroidal Section" I don't get anything even vaguely resembling the neatly sorted and classified cross-sections of cones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Toric section(s)*" should be a more successful search term.
I've recently completed an article about toric sections, their equation, short descriptions of their most renowned types and an unexpected relation with the cone-cylinder intersections.

[The toric sections: a simple introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00803)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That is very interesting and I will definitely read it. I had already identified Bernoulli's lemniscate (and its variants), but I had no idea how to classify the "tilted" sections!

Comment: Your text is a pure marvel. Too few people do 3D classical analytical geometry with figures. I attempt in my answers or questions (like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626356 : see fig. 2 and 3)  to provide pictures wherever I can.